# var, loop in javascript, cannot understand the output, error

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        arr[i] = function(){
            return i;
        };
    }
    document.write(arr[1]());
```

the output is 5, as I expected

but when i added i++ between return i; and the end of the for loop, like the code below,

```
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        arr[i] = function(){
            return i;
        };
        i++;
    }
    document.write(arr[1]());
```

screen shows the error,
Uncaught TypeError: arr[1] is not a function

i expected that output should be 6, but i cannot understand why.

Comment: Becuase after your first loop `i` will be `2`. I suggest using some debugging tools to look at your variables or add some `console.log()`'s to your code to understand what's going on next time.

Comment: Because you're increasing the index by 2, array[0], array[2], array[4]...

Comment: Are you also expecting all the functions within `arr` to output the same value? That's what will happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've got *two* increments for `i`, the assigned elements of the array will be `0`, `2`, and `4`. Element `1` is skipped.

The first assignment happens when `i` is 0. Then, `i` is incremented to 1 at the end of the loop, and then again to 2 in the third clause of the `for` loop header. So the next assignment is for element 2.

Comment: I can accept your answer 11mins later, anyway, thank you

Comment: Also, without a closure won't all the functions within `arr` will output `5`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that's true but apparently the OP already knows that; it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: Good point! I missed the last line, except the output won't be `6` it'd be `5`.